# Efficiently Search Through Array in Swift

Tags: arrays, performance, sorting, search, swift

I have a large array of PFObjects: `giantRestaurantArray`. I want to check if each array object `"FoodType"` contains any the types of food in `checkFoodOptionsArray`. If the type of food is found, add the food type to `foundFoodTypes` array.

The loop is inefficient because it checks the array over and over again (even if the food type already was found). How do I increase search performance and skip over `FoodTypes` that were already added?

```
 var checkFoodOptionsArray = ["American", "BBQ", "Breakfast", "Buffet", "Burgers", "Cafe", "Wings", "Chinese", "Dessert", "FastFood", "Indian", "Italian", "Japanese", "Korean", "Pizza", "Sandwiches", "Seafood", "Steakhouse", "Thai", "Mexican", "Vietnamese", "Vegan", "OtherEthnic"]

 for items in checkFoodOptionsArray { checkIfFoodTypeOptionAvailable(items) }

 func checkIfFoodTypeOptionAvailable(optionValue: String){
    let isAvailable = contains(giantRestaurantArray as [PFObject]) { (object) -> Bool in
        if let type = object["FoodType"] as? String {
            return type.rangeOfString(optionValue) != nil
        }
        else {
            return false
        }
    }
    if isAvailable == true {
        foundFoodTypes.append(optionValue)
    } else {
        println("No, array does not contain \(optionValue)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build a `Dictionary` of only the `FoodTypes`. Building could be a little expensive, but then lookups are basically free:

```
// create lookup dictionary
let foodTypes: [String: ()] = reduce(giantRestaurantArray as [PFObject], [:]) {
    (var result, object) in
    if let type = object["FoodType"] as? String {
        result[type] = ()
    }
    return result
}

// build list of un-matched foods:
let foundFoodTypes: [String] = checkFoodOptionsArray.filter {
    foodTypes[$0] != nil 
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i hadn't thought of building a dict for this. do you think this would perform faster than @fred02138 's answer?

Comment: That answer is equivalent to your current code. The performance difference with this one will probably depend on how big your arrays are—dictionaries are a little bit slow to create, but this way you're only looping through your giant array once, so if that really is giant you could see some real efficiency with this approach. Ideally you'll only need to do this once per lifecycle of your application.

Comment: Thanks Nate. If i wanted to apply the same search to `giantRestaurantArray` but with a different `object["PriceType"]` and array of options, would I need to build another dictionary. Or could I add it to the current dictionary without drastically increasing the expense?

Comment: You'd need another dictionary for that, since a dictionary can only have one key. You could still build it in one pass, you'd probably just want to do it in a more imperative style (i.e., `for item in array { add to dictionaries }`) than the functional one in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to terminate the search as soon as you find the item, so don't use `contains`.

```
func checkIfFoodTypeOptionAvailable(optionValue: String){
    let isAvailable = false

    for obj in giantRestaurantArray {
        if let object = obj as? PFObject {
            if let type = object["FoodType"] as? String {
                isAvailable = type.rangeOfString(optionValue) != nil
                if isAvailable {
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }


    if isAvailable == true {
        foundFoodTypes.append(optionValue)
    } else {
        println("No, array does not contain \(optionValue)")
    }
}
```

Comment: `contains` already has this behavior—the predicate isn't evaluated again after returning `true`.